# Gatsby JS Fragment Query into component with DatoCMS

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am trying to create a fragment and pass it down into components. The data is coming from datocms and normal queries such as the following work perfectly fine

```
{
  datoCmsHomeIntro {
    introTitle: introTitleNode {
      markdown: childMarkdownRemark {
        html
      }
    }
    introImage {
      url
    }
  }
}
```

I read through the gatsby docs on fragments and some other examples but just can't get it to work.

Right now what I got is this:

in layouts/index.js

```
export const introFragmentQuery = graphql`
fragment intro on DatoCmsHomeIntro {
  introTitle: introTitleNode {
    markdown: childMarkdownRemark {
      html
    }
  }
  introImage {
    url
  }
}
`
```

and in my component:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query IntroQuery {
    allDatoCmsHomeIntro {
      edges {
        node {
          ...intro
        }
      }
    }
}
`
```

I am obviously missing something so any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an error or is `data.allDatoCmsHomeIntro` undefined?

Comment: Yes basically no matter how I try to get it into the frontend, something always seems undefined. Also now re-reading the docs the next morning, I realize everything should be the other way around. So the actual query inside the components and the query calling he fragment inside the layout or page. Is that correct. Kinda confused by this whole thing ;)

Comment: Your graphql queries are statically compiled; i.e., they're pulled out of the JS and replaced with data before the JS is executed. Gatsby only uses your initial “page” query. You can put fragments elsewhere and use them on your “page”, but top level queries in those other files won't be executed for the “page” you're loading. Make sense?